# How to use reports in VisualStudio2010 from ReportBuilder 3.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a report called Summary from Report Builder 3.0 which i accessed from localhost/reports_2012.
I have saved the report on Desktop with a name summary and noticed it has .rdl format.
I opened up visualstudio2010 and created a webpage using asp.net webforms and drag and droped down reportViewer from ToolBox.
I Created a folder in solution explorer named it Reports and add an existing item to it (Summary report from Desktop)
on report viewer i can't find under dropdown summary.rdl
instead there is server report.

please help
How i can use my report created from Report Builder 3.0 from sql2012 with visual studio 2010 asp.net webforms ReportViewer

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to upload your report (RDL which was created with report builder) to a report server.

Then when your report is exist in the report server he will have a unique URL for it.

This URL start with your report server URL and then the location of your report on the report server.

For example a report server path

```
http://myrshost/reportserver?
```

For example report path location

```
/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory&rs:Command=Render
```

The full URL

```
http://myrshost/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory&rs:Command=Render
```

You can't put your report in your solution explorer and run t from there.

For more information look at the following links:

- [Report builder 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207008%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Report server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157231.aspx)
- [how to upload report to report server using report manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157332.aspx)